# Apache Htaccess forwarding sub folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to create a custom rule for `htaccess` so that all the URL's requested in the home         folder such as `localhost/asfsd` will redirect to `localhost/index.php?url=asfsd` but if the user enters the following url `localhost/asfsd-` he must then be forwarded to `localhost/info.php?url=asfsd` . Here is my current `.htaccess` configuration :

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.+?)-$ /info.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\-$ info.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks newman ... but it is still forwarding all the - trailing urls to index.php only.